# in event definition after init, why am I getting Error 18 Use of unassigned local variable 'beforeEvntDrawArg'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, compiler-errors

I have an event object...

```
public class BeforeEvntDrawArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Event html. 
    /// </summary>      
    internal string InnerHTML
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Html;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Html = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event tags, using Data TagFields.
    /// </summary>
    public Gamex.TagCollection Tag
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event text.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event Clue.
    /// </summary>
    public string HoverOver
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    internal BeforeEvntDrawArgs(Event e, string[] fields)
    {

        this.Id = e.Id;
        this.Text = e.Text;

        if (e.Tags != null)
        {
            this.Tag = new Gamex.TagCollection(fields, new List<string>(e.Tags));
        }


    }
}
```

While trying to bubble an event and copy the details, I get an Error    18  Use of unassigned local variable 'beforeEntDrawArg'

If I assign null `BeforeEvntDrawArgs beforeEvntDrawArg = null;` then it compiles fine, because the app bombs out saying `null ref`. Not sure what I am doing wrong, can you help me correct this code?

**However in the event body when I am copying and initializing, what am I doing wrong, why am I getting an uninitialized at compile time, and if I use a null, why does it break at runtime? Please let me know how to resolve this..**

```
  private BeforeEvntDrawArgs DoBeforeEvntDraw(Event e)
     {
         // Issue begins here, and pre-initializing to null compiles, 
         // however breaks on runtime as a null ref
         BeforeEvntDrawArgs beforeEvntDrawArg = new BeforeEvntDrawArgs(e, this.TagFields)
         {
            HoverOver = Encoder.HtmlEncode(beforeEvntDrawArg.Text),
            InnerHtml = Encoder.HtmlEncode(beforeEvntDrawArg.Text)
         };
         this.OnBeforeEvntDraw(beforeEvntDrawArg);
         return beforeEvntDrawArg;
     }
```

**Error 18  Use of unassigned local variable 'beforeEvntDrawArg'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use beforeEvntDrawArg from within it's own object initializer. This isn't supported. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Try this. It's exactly the same just without the object initialization syntax.

```
BeforeEvntDrawArgs beforeEvntDrawArg = new BeforeEvntDrawArgs(e, this.TagFields)
beforeEvntDrawArg.HoverOver = Encoder.HtmlEncode(beforeEvntDrawArg.Text);
beforeEvntDrawArg.InnerHtml = Encoder.HtmlEncode(beforeEvntDrawArg.Text);
```

Comment: This solved the issue, but I have been writing initalizers as anonymous functions for a long time... wondering why its not working.

Comment: There is no anonymous function in the code you posted above, just an object initializer. This is just syntactic sugar for exactly what is duplicated below except it doesn't give you access to the newed up object. Use ilspy on the code but change the assignment to assign a const string. You will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere in the class you posted (BeforeEvntDrawArgs
) a definition for a constructor that takes 2 arguments. This means that the only constructor available would be the default parameterless constructor. So when you are trying to perform

```
HoverOver = Encoder.HtmlEncode(beforeEvntDrawArg.Text)
```

beforeEvntDrawArg.Text has not yet been assigned a value.

Comment: I think this is a copy paste error, but: internal BeforeEvntRenderArgs(Event e, string[] fields) should be: internal BeforeEvntDrawArgs(Event e, string[] fields)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I think your answer has hit the nail on the head in answering the OP's question.

Comment: @Mike Kevin You're correct, that was a typeO while pasting markdown _here but not in my code_. Issue still is my code has the correct signature - and has these symptoms. Please suggest anything else you might see